# Possible to get an edit history log via script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, logging, edit

I have a Google Sheet where multiple users collaborate simultaneously. Within this sheet, I possess historical data dating back to 2022. However, I lack the associated email addresses for the individuals linked to specific rows. Nevertheless, I have access to the edit history. Is it feasible to retrieve these email addresses through a script and print them out?

I have tried many many things, thats one of them

```
function captureEmailForExistingCheckboxes() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('id');
var columnAOIndex = 41;
var targetColumnIndexEmail = columnAOIndex + 3;

var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
var checkboxValue = data[i][columnAOIndex - 1];
if (checkboxValue === true) {
var editedBy = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
sheet.getRange(i + 1, targetColumnIndexEmail).setValue(editedBy);
>     }
>   }
> }
```

Comment: AFAIK, ```No```